# Finding strongly connected components - Kosaraju’s Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

In directed graph, to find strongly connected components (with  Kosaraju’s Algorithm) why do we have to transpose adjacency matrix (reverses the direction of all edges) if we could use reversed list of nodes by they finishing time and then traverse original graph.
In other words, we would find finish times of all vertices and start traversing from lowest finish time to greatest (by increasing finish time)?

Additionally, if we do topological sorting on some DAG, and then reverse edges (transpose adjacency matrix) and do topological sorting again - should we get to equal arrays, just in reversed order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't give SCC. Consider 2 subgraphs S1 and S2. For both S1 and S2 to be a part of single SCC, there should be a path from S1 to S2 and also from S2 to S1. The way you mentioned it, it will count them as a single SCC even if there is only a path from S1 to S2.
DFS on both original and reversed graph makes sure that only components which have paths in both direction gets combined inside a SCC.

> Additionally, if we do topological sorting on some DAG, and then reverse edges (transpose adjacency matrix) and do topological sorting again - should we get to equal arrays, just in reversed order?

Not necessarily. Consider a trivial example (1->2,1->3) .Topological sort=(1,2,3). Reverse graph (2->1,3->1). Topological sort (2,3,1)